# Issues in Xunit.Assert.Collection - C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections, assert, xunit

I have a Class Library, it contains the following Model and Method

Model:

```
public class Employee {
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```
public class EmployeeService {
    public List<Employee> GetEmployee() {
        return new List<Employee>() {
            new Employee() { EmpId = 1, Name = "John" },
            new Employee() { EmpId = 2, Name = "Albert John" },
            new Employee() { EmpId = 3, Name = "Emma" },
        }.Where(m => m.Name.Contains("John")).ToList();
    }
}
```

I have a Test Method

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetEmployeeTest() {
    EmployeeService obj = new EmployeeService();
    var result = obj.GetEmployee();
    Xunit.Assert.Collection<Employee>(result, m => Xunit.Assert.Contains("John",m.Name));
}
```

I got an Exception message

```
Assert.Collection() Failure
Collection: [Employee { EmpId = 1, Name = "John" }, Employee { EmpId = 2, Name = "Albert John" }]
Expected item count: 1
Actual item count:   2
```

My requirement is to check all the `items.Name` should contain the sub string "John". Kindly assist me how to check using `Xunit.Assert.Collection`

Answer (score 76):

It appears that Assert.Collection only uses each element inspector once. So, for your test, the following works:

**If the sequence `result` has exactly two elements:**

```
[Fact]
public void GetEmployeeTest()
{
    EmployeeService obj = new EmployeeService();
    var result = obj.GetEmployee();

    Assert.Collection(result, item => Assert.Contains("John", item.Name),
                              item => Assert.Contains("John", item.Name));
}
```

**If there are many elements,** changing the `Assert` to

```cs
Assert.All(result, item => Assert.Contains("John", item.Name));
```

should give you the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 4):

This is an expansion on Ayb4btu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44345087/685341) for those who aren't interested in the order of items in the collection.

The following method is based on the original XUnit implementation, and will allow you to test using a very similar interface:

```
public static class TestExpect
{
public static void CollectionContainsOnlyExpectedElements<T>(IEnumerable<T> collectionToTest, params Func<T, bool>[] inspectors)
{
    int expectedLength = inspectors.Length;
    T[] actual = collectionToTest.ToArray();
    int actualLength = actual.Length;

    if (actualLength != expectedLength)
        throw new CollectionException(collectionToTest, expectedLength, actualLength);

    List<Func<T, bool>> allInspectors = new List<Func<T, bool>>(inspectors);
    int index = -1;
    foreach (T elementToTest in actual)
    {
        try
        {
            index++;
            Func<T, bool> elementInspectorToRemove = null;
            foreach (Func<T, bool> elementInspector in allInspectors)
            {
                if (elementInspector.Invoke(elementToTest))
                {
                    elementInspectorToRemove = elementInspector;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (elementInspectorToRemove != null)
                allInspectors.Remove(elementInspectorToRemove);
            else
                throw new CollectionException(collectionToTest, expectedLength, actualLength, index);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new CollectionException(collectionToTest, expectedLength, actualLength, index, ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The difference here is that for a collection

```
 string[] collectionToTest = { "Bob", "Kate" };
```

Both the following lines will not produce a `CollectionException`

```
 TestExpect.CollectionContainsOnlyExpectedElements(collectionToTest, x => x.Equals("Bob"), x => x.Equals("Kate"));
 TestExpect.CollectionContainsOnlyExpectedElements(collectionToTest, x => x.Equals("Kate"), x => x.Equals("Bob"));
```

Whereas using `Assert.Collection` - Only the first of the above two lines will work as the collection of inspectors is evaluated in order.

There is a potential performance impact using this method, but if you are only testing fairly small sized collections (as you probably will be in a unit test), you will never notice the difference.

Comment: You're a BOSS.  But this doesn't let you collections that aren't dictionaries - which was my problem.  For example `class TestData { public string FirstName {get;set;} }` and `Assert.Collection(new List<TestData>() { new TestData() { FirstName =  "Bob" } }, item => Assert.Contains("Bob", item.FirstName);` doesn't compile

Comment: (because it's not a dictionary, it's a list)

Comment: Hi @JohnZabroski - If I've understood your comment correctly, you should still be able to use my method like this... `TestExpect.CollectionContainsOnlyExpectedElements(new List<TestData>() { new TestData() {FirstName = "Bob"}}, x => "Bob".Equals(x.FirstName));` instead of `Assert.Collection.....`

Answer (score 4):

Use `Assert.Contains(result, item => item.Name == "John");`